# Отрисовка кругов в разных потоках

Tags: java, android, eclipse, canvas

Добрый день!

Имеются три круга, нарисованных с помощью Canvas.
Необходимо запустить в разных потоках смену цвета с разной периодичностью.
Пытаюсь реализовать через AsyncTask, но объекты не перерисовываются.
В чем проблема?

Класс:

```
public class Draw2D extends View{

    public Draw2D(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Ширина и высота прямоугольника
        int WidthRec  = 100;
        int HeightRec = 200;

        //Рассчитываем на основе холста и параметров высоты и ширины прямоугольника, точки для построения
        int tLeft   = (canvas.getWidth()/2)-WidthRec;
        int tRigth  = (canvas.getWidth()/2)+WidthRec;
        int tTop    = (canvas.getHeight()/2)-HeightRec;
        int tBottom = (canvas.getHeight()/2)+HeightRec;

        int RadiusCir = 30;
        int Spaces    = 70;
        int tCxCir    = canvas.getWidth()/2;
        int tCyCir1   = tTop+RadiusCir+Spaces;
        int tCyCir2   = tCyCir1+RadiusCir+Spaces;
        int tCyCir3   = tCyCir2+RadiusCir+Spaces;


        //Цвет заливки
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);

        //Прямоугольник
        mPaint.reset();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(tLeft,tTop,tRigth,tBottom, mPaint);

        //1 Круг
        mPaint.reset();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawCircle(tCxCir, tCyCir1, RadiusCir, mPaint);

        //2 Круг
        canvas.drawCircle(tCxCir, tCyCir2, RadiusCir, mPaint);

        //3 Круг
        canvas.drawCircle(tCxCir, tCyCir3, RadiusCir, mPaint);

        if (FlagFirst)
        {
            asyncTask1 = new MyAsyncTask(canvas,tCxCir, tCyCir1, RadiusCir, 1100, this);
            asyncTask2 = new MyAsyncTask(canvas,tCxCir, tCyCir2, RadiusCir, 2443, this);
            asyncTask3 = new MyAsyncTask(canvas,tCxCir, tCyCir3, RadiusCir, 3750, this);

            asyncTask1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            asyncTask3.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            FlagFirst = false;

        }

    }
}
```

Ансинхронный поток:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    final int[] CountColor = {Color.RED,Color.YELLOW,Color.GREEN};
    private int mCx;
    private int mCy;
    private int mR;
    private int UsDelay;
    private Canvas mcanvas;
    private View mV;

    public MyAsyncTask(Canvas canvas, int Cx, int Cy, int R, int delay, View v) {
        mCx = Cx;
        mCy = Cy;
        mR = R;
        UsDelay = delay;
        mcanvas = canvas;
        mV = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        int i = 0;
        while (true){
            if (i > 2){ i = 0;}
            publishProgress(i);
            i++;
            SystemClock.sleep(UsDelay);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {


        mPaint.reset();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mcanvas.drawCircle(mCx, mCy, mR, mPaint);

        mPaint.reset();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(CountColor[values[0]]);
        mcanvas.drawCircle(mCx, mCy, mR, mPaint);
        mV.invalidate();

    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте вместо invalidate() вызвать postInvalidate()

Comment: Не помогло, все так же статично. http://s008.radikal.ru/i304/1609/c1/1e7f6b634589.jpg